# Method stops after open a new session with Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a photo from my android app to facebook wall, it works but I need to use the post button twice, the first authorization is for login, and the second one is to authorize my app.

I don't know why after asking for a new session, i.e `Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);`, the rest of my method kind of stops running, so after I call the method again, it now asks for app permission and post

Below is the part that is concerned:

Call this when I hit the post button `performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, false);`

```
private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {

    // check for log in first
    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    } 
        // the method stops here
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
            return;
        } else if (session.isOpened()) {
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, "publish_actions"));
            return;
        }
    }

    if (allowNoSession) {
        pendingAction = action;
        handlePendingAction();
    }
}
```

These are the rest but they don't matter to this issue

```
   @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

private void postPhoto() {
     if (hasPublishPermission()) {


    //if (Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().contains("publish_actions") && (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()))
            showLoading();
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), myBm, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    hideLoading();
                    showPublishResult("photo_post", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo successfully uploaded to Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); 

            // photo's description
            if (moment.name != null)
                parameters.putString("message",moment.name);

            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }
        else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest of your method stops running after you call openActiveSession because opening a session is asynchronous. So right after your call to openActiveSession, the session is NOT open. It starts another activity (LoginActivity) which prompts the user, etc, and then the answer comes back via the onActivityResult method.

If you want to handle it in a single click, you should add some code in your status callback, and check if there's a pending publish, and if so, do the publish at that point.

The HelloFacebook sample app that ships with the SDK demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: I got these codes from HelloFacebook, but that app only lets you post after you have logged in, then you click on the post button, which are 2 steps also, how would I do this in one step?

Comment: You don't. You're already required (by policy) to separate the requests of read and publish permissions, so that's 2 requests already. The recommended flow is for the app to ask for read permissions when the user first starts your app, and then ask for publish permissions later when it actually needs it. This way, the user understands why you're asking for these permissions, and are more likely to grant them to you.

Comment: so you mean there's no way to do login and authorization in 1 step? it has to ask permission twice?

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic here, but what I stated was that you need to separate read and publish permissions. Authorization has many meanings, and requesting read permissions is also a form of authorization (and in that case, you can login and authorize in 1 step). It's just that you need to ask for publish permissions separately. Furthermore, you only need to ask for publish permissions ONCE, and after the user grants you publish permissions, you don't need to ask for it again.